# Webform CiviCRM - add to group option

Tags: webform-civicrm

We all know the Drupal Webform CiviCRM auto add to group option.

But how do we allow a user to select which groups they get added to?

Specifically I'd like them to opt in/out to a newsletter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it a -user select-  and then if you want to narrow down the options -> switch the element configuration to static (live is default). When static you can not only decide whixh Groups a user can select - you can also order them - and relabel them.

Comment: Also, can use conditionals to turn it into a checkbox :)